# statement cannot resolve address of overloaded function

Tags: c++, overloading

I encountered that eror in the following function. Does anyone have an idea what it means?

```
template <class T>
void printAll(Array <T> &A){
    for(int i=0; i<31; i++){
        A.M[i].printObj; ///// ERROR
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

The function should print all my objects. `.printObj` works because I tested it in the class print function. Thank you, and for any more details I may have forgotten please ask.

Comment: Have you tried adding parentheses (and possibly arguments) so that you call `printObj`?

Answer (score 6):

The parameters to the call are missing. Probably, you meant something like

```
    A.M[i].printObj();
```